# How to catch local notification onclick event in phonegap

Tags: notifications, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Thank you very much for the plugin!
I'm having a bit of a problem: My onclick doesn't seem to be getting called

```js
  window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id:          1,
            date:        dateobj,
            message:    'Test Notification',
            title:      'MyApp',
            repeat:     'daily',
            badge:       1,
            autoCancel:  true
        });
        window.plugin.notification.local.onclick = function(id, state, json){
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            alert("success");
        };
```

I also tried the oncancel just now and it is the same... Nothing happens. 
Edit: onadd seems to work fine though. Probably because app is already open when I do an add?
    The notification appears fine and the app loads when I click it, but I don't see anything in console and don't see the alert. Am I correct in assuming the onclick should be fired after user clicks notification and the app loads?

```
I'm using phonegap build 3.1, plugin 0.7.0, android 4.3. Am I missing anything?
```

Comment: Which plugin do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, the click event will be called after device ready. It seems something wrong on assigning click event to the notification. Try to use the following one. Hope it will help to you.

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification) {
joinMeeting(notification.data.meetingId);});
```